# How Request.IsAuthenticated work in mvc4 exactly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I made 2 MVC Project that use login form before start 
I use this code for login

```
 public ActionResult Login(AccountLog Usr)
    {
        AccountLog personindatabase = db.AccountLogs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Usercode == Usr.Usercode);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(personindatabase.UserName, true);
                ViewBag.id = personindatabase.Usersid;
                return RedirectToAction("Main", "Main");}
```

when I run program at I check first `if(Request.IsAuthenticated)` if true return view if else redirect to login page as this

```
 public ActionResult Main()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

    }
```

it worked fine but I noticed that if I run the first program and made success login and close it not made logout and run the second program that not logged yet it open as it logged person this mean if i made login from the first one and open the second it will open fine and vise versa how can i differentiate between 2 project login how can i made alternative for `Request.IsAuthenticated` if any thing in question don't clear leave comment to clear it to be able to help me

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying two different logins at the same time using the same browser ?

Comment: yes i did this the same browser but not in the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you just described you are trying to login to the same application using the same browser session in two different tabs without logging out the first user.

When a login is a success an `Authentication Cookie` is set in the browser. This cookie is sent to the server each time so that the server can validate the user.

As you are trying to login ( or expect to login) into the second tab using another account, you already see the first user logged in as the `Authentication Cookie` for that account still persisted in the browser. The Authentication cookie will expire only when the user logs off.

So you can either.

1. Test two accounts using two different browsers(e.g. Chrome and Firefox)
2. Log off the first account before trying to login using another account in the same browser.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Man i not mean  2 person login to the same application but i mean 2 different application say application 1 called supermarket and application 2 called zoo this is submission   if i use the same browser and attempt to login to the supper market app and close it without logout and in the same browser attempt to run second application it open as it logged with the person that logged from the first application although the 2 application use different database i hope to understand to help me